# Komma vor „und“

Tags: sentence-structure, conjunction, punctuation

Ich habe folgenden Satz gesehen:

> Diese Zeitung hat immer ein interessantes Thema, und ich habe nun auch ein Thema gefunden, das ich gern diskutieren würde.

Ist das Komma vor *und* richtig? Wenn die Antwort „Ja“ ist, was ist der Grund für diese Verwendung?

Comment: Hallo, und willkommen auf German.SE! Hast du schon eigene Recherche betrieben? Bei Fragen zur Kommasetzung und anderen Rechtschreibregeln ist der Duden immer eine gute erste Anlaufstelle. Hilft dir vielleicht https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/komma weiter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Der Satz besteht aus den zwei selbständigen Sätzen:

> - Diese Zeitung hat immer ein interessantes Thema.
> - Ich habe nun auch ein Thema gefunden, das ich gern diskutieren würde.

Daher greift § 73 des [amtlichen Regelwerks](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6201#), wonach vor *und* ein Komma gesetzt werden kann, aber nicht muss:

> **§ 73**
>
> Bei der Reihung von selbständigen Sätzen, die durch *und*, *oder*, *beziehungsweise*/*bzw.*, *entweder – oder*, *nicht – noch* oder durch *weder – noch* verbunden sind, kann man ein Komma setzen, um die Gliederung des Ganzsatzes deutlich zu machen.

Comment: Hi, I am not a fan of the trickery in you user name. Just saying.

Comment: @CarstenS, me neither. But StackExchange doesn't allow me to change it: *"Oops! There was a problem updating your profile: Display name may only be changed once every 30 days; you may change again on Feb 22 at 14:31"*

Comment: Ha, that's okay then ;)

Answer (score 0):

Der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/komma) sagt hierzu:

> Das Komma steht zwischen den Teilen von Reihungen (Aufzählungen).[...] Es steht allerdings kein Komma bei Reihungen, deren Elemente mit Konjunktionen des Typs und/oder verbunden sind. [...] Bei gereihten Hauptsätzen, die mit solchen Konjunktionen verbunden sind, darf hingegen ein Komma gesetzt werden.

In Deinem Beispiel werden zwei Hauptsätze mit *und* verbunden. Das Komma ist damit möglich, aber nicht obligatorisch.

Comment: [Offizielle Rechtschreibregeln](https://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2016_redigiert_2018.pdf), § 73: "Bei der Reihung von selbständigen Sätzen, die durch *und*, *oder*, *beziehungsweise/bzw.*, *entweder – oder*, *nicht – noch* oder durch *weder
– noch* verbunden sind, kann man ein Komma setzen, um die Gliederung des Ganzsatzes deutlich zu machen."